# Applescript XML Parse Header

Tags: xml, parsing, header, applescript

I searched here and Google and came up with nothing, so I am hoping that someone here can help me understand how to parse "href=" from the XML Header in the following example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo version="2" href="/event/189" product="Server">
    <name>The Name</name>
</foo>
```

Here is what I do know.  To parse the element "name" in the xml file, I can do the following:

```
set source_xml to choose file "Select your xml source"
set posix_source_xml to POSIX path of source_xml

tell application "System Events"
    set xml_file to XML file posix_source_xml
    tell xml_file
        tell XML element "foo"
            set name_value to value of XML element "name"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

But how do I get the value for "href=" in the "foo" header?  I tried this with no success:

```
set source_xml to choose file "Select your xml source"
set posix_source_xml to POSIX path of source_xml

tell application "System Events"
    set xml_file to XML file posix_source_xml
    tell xml_file
        set foo_value to value of XML element "foo"
    end tell
end tell
```

Even if that did work, I would imagine it would return - version="2" href="/event/189" product="Server" - and not just - /event/189.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hey @snwbrdr78 how did this go? Did you have any luck with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

There is an `XML attribute` property.

To get href from your example:

```
set href_value to value of XML attribute "href" of XML element "foo"
```